# Get System > Config value through ajax

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, ajax

Is it possible to get System > Config values through ajax.  Or jQuery?

Comment: No, but you can write a controller which will do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create your own controller for that just follow these are the steps for that
create your `config.xml` file in your module

```
<config>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
        <yourid>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>YourPackge_YourExtension</module>
                <frontName>yourfrontname</frontName>
            </args>
        </yourid>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

in your module `controller` folder create `IndexController.php` file 
with below code

```
<?php
class YourPackage_YourModule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
    indexAction(){
          echo Mage::getStoreConfig('sectionName/groupName/fieldName');
    }
}
```

And that file where you firing ajax call you will get this text or value in `response`.